# ImmutableJS.Set - Add or Remove depending on bool

Tags: javascript, set, immutable.js

Is there a one-liner for Immutable.Set that will either add() or remove() a value depending on a bool?

Of course this can be done with:

```
if (listShouldHaveFooBool) {
  mySet.add('foo');
}
else {
  mySet.remove('foo');
}
```

But is there a one-liner that would work like this? (using a made-up .modify() method)

```
// mySet = ['foo', 'bar', baz']
// listShouldHaveFooBool = false;
mySet.modify('foo', listShouldHaveFooBool);
// mySet = ['bar', baz']
listShouldHaveFooBool = true;
mySet.modify('foo', listShouldHaveFooBool);
// mySet = ['foo', 'bar', baz']
```

But I'm looking for a one-liner that I can easily drop into a object literal declaration like a React setState:

```
this.setState({ mySet: mySet.modify(value, shouldHaveValue)});
```

Tertiary operator would work, but it's ugly:

```
this.setState({ mySet: shouldHaveValue ? mySet.add(value) : mySet.remove(value)});
```

Hmm... Ok, that's not bad... but still: Is there an all-in-one Immutable method for this?

Comment: `Immutable.Set` does not provide a "non-ugly" way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a function for it?

```
this.setState({ mySet: modify(mySet)(value)(shouldHaveValue) })
```

And then write a one-line function like:

```
const modify = set => value => shouldBe => shouldBe === value ? set.add(value) : set.remove(value)
```

I'm not sure why your using `Sets` but if you use `Maps` or `Lists` you can update their values and could use predicate their to determine whether the value is created or not.

**ES5**

```js
var modify = function(set){
  return function(value){
    return function(shouldBe){
      return shouldBe === value ? set.add(value) : set.remove(value);
    };
  };
};
```